# Merging master branch into feature branch then back again

Tags: git, merge, branch

I have a feature branch that was branched from my master branch a some time ago. I have since developed quite a lot of additional features, which have all now been merged into the master branch. Now I need to merge the master branch into this old feature branch (to get some important code updates from the master branch). Can I do this and then, once I have completed testing on this old feature branch, merge it back into the master branch (prior to going live)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

This is actually good practice - keep the branches up-to-date with master so that when they eventually are ready to be merged back to master there is little/no risk of conflicts, and the branch code has been tested along against the then-latest changes in master.

Comment: With regards to the traceability of the merges, etc., won't this cause a circular reference to occur?

Comment: Afaik it's impossible to create circular references with Git.